# change tab position on item click event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, tabs

i have 3 tabs : 1st is Setting, 2nd is Home and 3rd is list..
Now in 1st tab i have used list view, on item click event i want to move on 2 nd tab.
i have applied code but onItemClick i am only moving on 1st tab (1st tab changes in to Home tab)...

here i want to change the tab position..

please help me to change the tab position..

here is my code..

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
                        ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment1, true);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you mention it would be a good idea to use Viewpager  instead. Useful example here. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter